# Difference between cursor.fetchall() and pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, sql, pandas, database-cursor, fetchall

I know there are a few ways to retrieve data from RDB table.
One with pandas as read_sql, the other with cursore.fetchall().
What are the main differences between both ways in terms of:

1. memory usage - is df less reccomended?
2. performance - selecting data from a table (e.g. large set of data)
3. performace - inserting data with a loop for cursor vs df.to_sql.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

That's an interesting question.
For a ~10GB SQLite database, I get the following results for your second question.
`pandas.sql_query` seems comparable to speed with the `cursor.fetchall`.

The rest I leave as an exercise. :D

```py
import sqlite3
import time
import pandas as pd

def db_operation(db_name):
    connection = sqlite3.connect(db_name)
    c = connection.cursor()
    yield c
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()

start = time.perf_counter()
for i in range(0, 10):
    with db_operation('components.db') as c:
            c.execute('''SELECT * FROM hashes WHERE (weight > 50 AND weight < 100)''')
            fetchall = c.fetchall()

time.perf_counter() - start
2.967 # fractional seconds


start = time.perf_counter()
for i in range(0, 10):
    connection = sqlite3.connect('components.db')
    sql_query = pd.read_sql_query('''SELECT * FROM hashes WHERE (weight > 50 AND weight < 100)''', con = connection)
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()

time.perf_counter() - start
2.983 # fractional seconds
```

The difference is that `cursor.fetchall()` is a bit more spartan (=plain).
`pandas.read_sql_query` returns a `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>` and so you can use all the methods of `pandas.DataFrame`, like `pandas.DataFrame.to_latex`, `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv` `pandas.DataFrame.to_excel`, etc. ([documentation link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/frame.html))

One can accomplish the same exact goals with `cursor.fetchall`, but needs to press some or a lot extra keys.

Comment: Thanks you for your input. Is this considered to be a minor difference, or by definition, the use with cursore is better?

Comment: @Liorb Yes, the performance differences virtually don't exist. However, I updated the answer: there are differences a bit further,  in the easiness to further use the resulting data frame.